# How to copy a SQL Agent Job on same Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

I want to make a few duplicate copies of an existing SQL Server Agent Job on the same server and edit them to do the same action on different databases that exist on the same server.

These are multiple step agent jobs which would be a bit more work to recreate manually. I know I can create a script from an agent job to run on a different server, but I don't think that will work on the same database server. How can I achieve this without recreating the agent job from scratch and without replacing the existing job?

Ultimately I want to end up with about 5 duplicates of the original job...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm certain that this isn't the most elegant solution, but it will work. You'll need the `dbatools` PowerShell module, which you can install from the PSGallery with `install-module dbatools` or via the other methods at https://dbatools.io/install

Once `dbatools` is installed, from a PowerShell prompt/console, run the following:

```
Get-DbaAgentJob -SqlInstance YOURINSTANCE -Job "YOUR_SOURCE_JOB_NAME" | Export-DbaScript -FilePath c:\tmp\MyJobToCopy.sql
```

You can then open up that SQL file in Management Studio, change every instance of `YOUR_SOURCE_JOB_NAME` to the "new" name you want the copy of the job to have, and execute the SQL. Lather, rinse, repeat for the other 4 copies you need.

This could definitely be better as a self-contained script to do the name changes and query execution all in one go. But for a one-off, this will get you where you need to go.

If you were copying this job out to 5 *different* instances with the same name everywhere, it'd be a lot cleaner & easier thanks to `Copy-DbaAgentJob` (also from `dbatools`).

Comment: Would this cause problems with the script generated having the same schedule_uid and name as the original job? Should I edit the schedule creation statements out?

Comment: I think (been a while since I've done this) it will just put all the copies of the job on the same shared schedule.

Comment: Looks like this worked fine for me. I was able to make multiple copies of the job, though, I did comment out the schedule creation commands so I could handle scheduling manually.